# How to search JSON array contains item in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, where-clause

I have type images (`json`) in my db. Its array of strings.

How can I select all rows that `images` contains `"foo"` ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `json_contains()`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where json_contains(images, '"foo"')
```

Comment: it throw `Invalid JSON text in argument 2 to function json_contains: "Invalid value." at position 1.`

Comment: @sayicej101: my bad, it looks like we need double quotes around the value. See my update.

Comment: Man u saved my day, i was facing same issue @sayicej101